# How to change color of text or how to make this text as highlighted text?

Tags: android

I am working on one app.In this app. have one image with some text. I want show when I click or when I entered in text area I want show this text as highlighted text or I want to change color of this text.

Is it possible in android.Then give some suggestion to me.

My image is here..

[image]

Comment: detecting tap on text inside an image will be really complex and you might need open cv to do it. a simpler solution would be to make the text part as TextView yourself programatically and do not have any text in the image

Comment: Is this text attached to the image?

Comment: #shubhank,I know this solution ,but I am looking if any possible way using sensor or  OCR (Optical character recognition).open cv means?

Comment: #Ashwin S Ashok, Ashwin this is the whole image.There is no text attched

Comment: Using OCR to make a text clickable is difficult I think